# Why click event on d3.js resuable chart creating problem?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have used the pattern of reusable charts described by mike bostock. I am facing one problem.

**Pie Chart functionality** :-
1. When i click on a tab of pie chart, it should rotate and put the color which i clicked, on top.

**Problem** :-
1. When i click on first chart. The functionality is implemented but it is implemented on 2nd chart.

I think the problem is related to global declaration. But i haven't declared anything globally.

Please someone help me with this pretty basic task.

This is my js fiddle link where you can check this anamoly. 
https://jsfiddle.net/a0u2nk47/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                /*background-image: url("Computer.png");*/
            }
            p{
                float:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <!-- <img src=Computer.png width="70%" height="100%"> -->
    <p id="chart1"></p>
    <p id="chart2"></p>

<body >

    <script>
        function piechart(){
            var width = 400;
            var height = 400;
            var colors = ['red','green','blue']
            var innerRadius = 40;
            var outerRadius = 60;
            var index = 0;

            var pie = d3.pie()
                .sort(null);

            var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius).cornerRadius(5).padAngle(0.05);                

            function chart(selection){
                selection.each(function() {

                    svg = d3.select(this)
                            .append('svg')
                            .attr('width',width)
                            .attr('height',height)
                            .append('g')
                            .attr('transform','translate('+width/2+','+height/2+')')

                    path = svg.selectAll("path")
                       .data(pie(data))
                       .enter()
                       .append('path')
                       .attr('d',function(d){return arc(d)})
                       .style('fill',function(d,i){return colors[i]})
                       .style('stroke','black')
                       .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

                    updateData = function(){
                        path.data(pie(data))
                        path.transition().duration(2000).attrTween("d", arcTween);
                    }
                    updateWidth = function(){
                        innerRadius = width*0.6
                        outerRadius = width*0.8
                        arc.innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius);
                        path.transition().duration(1000).attr('d',function(d){return arc(d)});                                                      
                    }
                    path.on("click",chart.click);

                })
            }
            function arcTween(a) {                
              var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
              this._current = i(0);
              return function(t) {
                return arc(i(t));
              };
            }

            chart.data = function(value){

                if(!arguments.length) return data;
                data = value;
                if(typeof updateData === 'function') updateData();
                return chart;
            }

            chart.width = function(value){
                if(!arguments.length) return width;
                width = value;
                if(typeof updateWidth === 'function') updateWidth();
                return chart;
            }

            chart.click = function(value){
                debugger;
                index = this.__data__.index
                console.log(index)
                var rotate = 0-(value.startAngle + value.endAngle)/2 / Math.PI * 180;

                // Transition the pie chart
                svg.transition()
                   .attr("transform", "translate("+width/2+","+height/2+") rotate(" + rotate + ")")
                   .duration(1000);
            }
            return chart
        }
        data = [1,5,8];
        var piechart1 = piechart().data(data);
        d3.select('#chart1').call(piechart1);
        var piechart2 = piechart().data(data);
        d3.select('#chart2').call(piechart2);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `svg` and `data` are not part of your `chart` object, they are global variables. `data` is a function and also a variable

Comment: So what should i do to make it work @rioV8 ? Because whole point of reusable chart is to make it work for different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're transitioning/transforming the `<g>` element which is the parent of the `path`s you click on, you can just use `this.parentNode` to transform it.

For example, in the `click` handler, change the following:

```
svg.transition().attr('....
```

to

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).transition().attr('...
```

Although I'd suggest you assign an ID to each of the charts to separate them out in case of a reusable chart logic and use this newly created ID for all other functionalities instead of depending on the global variables. For instance:

```
var piechart1 = piechart(1).data(data); // pass an ID here
```

and assign it the following way:

```
svg.append('g').attr('id', 'container_' + id) // assign the ID
```

Here's a snippet followed with a fiddle fork:

```js
   function piechart(id){
    var width = 300;
    var height = 300;
    var colors = ['red','green','blue']
    var innerRadius = 40;
    var outerRadius = 60;
    var index = 0;

    var pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null);

    var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius).cornerRadius(5).padAngle(0.05);    

    function chart(selection){
     selection.each(function() {
      svg = d3.select(this)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width',width)
        .attr('height',height)
        .append('g').attr('id', 'container_' + id)
        .attr('transform','translate('+width/2+','+height/2+')')
      
      path = svg.selectAll("path")
         .data(pie(data))
         .enter()
         .append('path')
         .attr('d',function(d){return arc(d)})
         .style('fill',function(d,i){return colors[i]})
         .style('stroke','black')
         .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

      path.on("click",chart.click);

     })
    }
    chart.data = function(value){

     if(!arguments.length) return data;
     data = value;
     if(typeof updateData === 'function') updateData();
     return chart;
    }

    chart.click = function(value){
     index = this.__data__.index
           var rotate = 0-(value.startAngle + value.endAngle)/2 / Math.PI * 180;
              
           // Transition the pie chart
           d3.select(this.parentNode).transition()
              .attr("transform", "translate("+width/2+","+height/2+") rotate(" + rotate + ")")
              .duration(1000);
    }
    return chart
   }
   data = [1,5,8];
   var piechart1 = piechart(1).data(data);
   d3.select('#chart1').call(piechart1);
   var piechart2 = piechart(2).data(data);
   d3.select('#chart2').call(piechart2);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /*background-image: url("Computer.png");*/
   }
   p{
    float:left;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <!-- <img src=Computer.png width="70%" height="100%"> -->
 <p id="chart1"></p>
 <p id="chart2"></p>

 <body >

 </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rL96uv4g/

Hope this helps.